# Are there any good Salarian Engineer Specs.?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

As of now  my Level 8 Salarian Engineer who was promoted not only two hours ago, resetting his rank, is equipped with the M-4 Shuriken V, along with the SMG Magazine Upgrade I and the SMG High Caliber Barrel I

Energy Drain and Incinerate each have the first three levels upgraded, along with one in the Salarian Operative skill; leaving me with eighteen points left.

What would be the best thing to focus on next?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use him on Gold or Platinum then you should have full Decoy. I'd go so far as to say use either Energy Drain or Incinerate (I'm partial to Energy Drain myself) but not both. Decoy is useful in that it pulls aggro, giving some measure of crowd control. You'll be a bit squishy so get your health and shields as high as possible.